# Algorithm for recommending an item for a set based on another set

Tags: algorithm

Say I have a corpus of items (comma-separated in this example):

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

User A has items 1, 2 and 3. User B has items 2, 3, and 4. User A and User B match on two out of their three items. User A should be recommended item 3, and User B should be recommended item 1.

I'm bad at finding algorithms based on vague descriptions, but from what I can tell, [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) may be what I'm looking for. Am I correct in understanding that? If not, is there something else that will work better?

Comment: What is the criteria in your algorithm for recommendations?

Comment: Why wouldn't either of the two users be recommended items 5, 6, 7, or 8?

Comment: @AmirAfghani - the criteria would be based on the matching items each user has. If this was Amazon and I had bought the same two cables that another user has, I might be recommended a third item that user had also purchased.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - they both would, yes. The users would be able to pick from all the available items, but the recommendations would be weighted based on similar items between users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 You firstly need a clustering algorithm to separate your users to k classes.
for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering
Of course, there are tons of other clustering algorithms for you too. Also you can consider neural network.

2 After that, you can compare users within group then to recommend items based on difference between common items in group and items this user had.
This step could be straightforward. you can maintain a "Set" of common goods in group. Then you iterate users to calculate diffs.